# Making a button in a GUI that will remove contents of a .txt file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

Hi I'm trying to make a clear button for an application. When I click on the clear button nothing happens (That's probably because I'm knew to python). I've looked everywhere but I can't find an answer so if someone could help me that would be great (By the way I posted all of the code I wrote).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Application Launcher')
apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt', 'r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]


def addApp():

    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
                                        filetypes=(("executables", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
        label.pack()

def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)

def clearApps():
    if 'save.txt' in os.path.("save.txt")():
        os.remove('save.txt')
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Removed!', 'Successfully Removed!')
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror('Error!', 'File not found!')


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg="#262e2e")

canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#262e2e")
frame.place(relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.7, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="black", bg="white", command=addApp)

openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10, 
                    pady=5, fg="black", bg="white", command= runApps)

runApps.pack()

clearApps = tk.Button(root, text="Clear")

clearApps.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()

with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
        f.write(app + ',')
```

Comment: why do you say that something is wrong? ... instead of saying `I don't know what's wrong`, say what actually happens

Comment: os.remove *deletes* the file entirely, is that what you want?

Comment: @jsotola Done I changed the title

Comment: another question of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930888/my-clear-button-works-but-the-apps-dont-go-away

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about clearing app list, you didn't assign a command to your Clear button.

```
clearApps = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=clearApps)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930888/my-clear-button-works-but-the-apps-dont-go-away